# How to prevent push to main or dev branches while being in another branch using husky?

Tags: bash, git, husky

```
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

BRANCH=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
PROTECTED_BRANCHES="^(master|develop)"


if [[ $1 != *"$BRANCH"* ]]
//here why $1 is "origin"? it causes a push to same current branch to fail
then
  echo -e "\n You can only push to the current branch $BRANCH && exit 1
fi

if [[ "$BRANCH" =~ $PROTECTED_BRANCHES ]]
then
  echo -e "\n Cannot push to remote $BRANCH branch, please create your own branch and use PR." && exit 1
fi

echo -e ">> Finish checking branch name"

exit 0
```

Trying to set up husky but I am having few problems. Here $1 always refer to origin. SO suppose I am in feature/milan" and I am trying to push to same branch "feature/milan" I get error "You can only push to the current branch. I thought here $1 means the branch I am trying to push to. So trying to push using command git push origin branch/milan it will always fail even though I am trying to push into the same branch I am currently in.

Second issue, suppose I am in feature/milan branch and try to push to master or development it is not getting prevented maybe cause the current branch is feature/milan and this hook only prevents commit or hook when I am itself in protected which is master or dev.

Is there any way to get the name of a branch I am trying to push to? git push origin feature/milan. I thought $1 here means feature/milan...but here it is origin which is causing all these issues.

Comment: If `$1` maps to `origin` for your `git push origin <branch>` command... did you try to output what's in `$2`?

Comment: in `bash`, `$1` is the first argument that is passed down to the script that is being run.

Comment: ... unless you are messing up with the parameters (shifting, for example) in `/_/husky.sh`...  and it could be so because you are _sourcing_ it.

Comment: Anyway... the upstream of the current branch could be retrieved with `@{u}`.... I would assume it will prepend the remote name if it's a remote branch.